# How to Efficiently Draw Shadows on Numerous CALayers in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer

I've got some card games which use CALayers to draw individual cards. There can easily be 40 or 50 of them on the screen, which usually works fine.

I recently tried to turn on their shadows using the simple properties for CALayers:

```
theCardLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3,2);
theCardLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
```

At that point, the program started getting really laggy. Fair enough; some of the docs said that the shadows could be CPU-intensive.

Any ideas for how to efficiently draw shadows on everything? They're all on the same CALayer in the same UIView, so I'm wondering if there might be a way to pull the mask of the layer or its UIView and shadow that, or something  ...

Any functionality up to iOS5 is fair game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least, try setting your layer's `shadowPath` property. It can make shadow rendering significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Kurt offered up the correct solution. Here's an example of how to use a shadowPath:

```
UIBezierPath *thisCLPath = [UIBezierPath 
                            bezierPathWithRoundedRect:theCardLayer.bounds 
                            cornerRadius:10.0f];
theCardLayer.shadowPath = thisCLPath.CGPath;
```

Clearly, I'm using rounded corners here. For a straight-edged layer, you can just use `bezierPathWithRect:`. There are a few other helpful methods in UIBezierPath as well.

The result is just the right side of laggy on older iOS devices (like an iPhone4 or a mid-generation iPod Touch) and blazing on an iPad3.